# How do you dynamically place the current web address in a html href tag?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, facebook

I'm trying to use FB to share my blog.  I need to put the web address in a href but I don't know how to dynamically get the blog address into the href.  Is there a way to do this?  I use Angular in my app and I do not know JQuery.

Here is the code given my FB:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" data-layout="button_count"></div>
```

To be clear, I want to dynamically get the current page web address and put it in data-href since each blog post will have its own page/web address/location.

Comment: you can use window.location to check the current url address

Comment: @Bart Yes, I know that but I don't think I can make data-href=window.location can I?

Comment: no, you cannot do that, you can do $(".fb-share-button").attr("data-href", window.location)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller you could assign it to a `$scope` variable. `$scope.webpageAddress= window.location;` Then in your html:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="{{ webpageAddress }}" data-layout="button_count"></div>
```

Comment: @Matthew Berg - thanks! I should've figured this out but I didn't see it for some reason.